# Pandas - Create new column where values are taken from other rows in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` like this:

```
    message_id  reply_to_id     sender
0   1           0               Roozbeh
1   2           1               Amir
2   3           0               Neda
3   4           2               Roozbeh
3   5           2               Neda
```

If the message was a reply to another message, `reply_to_id` shows the id of the message that it was replied to, otherwise it's `0`. Now I want to create another column, `reply_to_sender`, where it shows the name of the sender of the message that it was replied to (and if it wasn't a reply, it can show `NaN`)

The `message_id` column is *unique,* but `reply_to_id` and `sender` columns are obviously not.

I tried this:

```
data["reply_to_sender"] = data.loc[data["reply_to_id"] == data["message_id"]]["sender"]
```

But it obviously won't work, because it looks at each row and perform the relational operation. What I'm trying to do is to look at each row and then find the name of the sender **from other rows**. For the example above, the output needs to be like this:

```
    message_id  reply_to_id     sender    reply_to_sender
0   1           0               Roozbeh   NaN
1   2           1               Amir      Roozbeh
2   3           0               Neda      NaN
3   4           2               Roozbeh   Amir
3   5           2               Neda      Amir
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with `Series` created by `message_id` and `sender`:

```
df['reply_to_sender'] = df['reply_to_id'].map(df.set_index('message_id')['sender'])
print (df)
   message_id  reply_to_id   sender reply_to_sender
0           1            0  Roozbeh             NaN
1           2            1     Amir         Roozbeh
2           3            0     Neda             NaN
3           4            2  Roozbeh            Amir
3           5            2     Neda            Amir
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's see how you would do this yourself, by hand. Then we implement it in code.

If I give you a `reply_to_id`, you can tell me who this message was a reply to, by simply looking at the `DataFrame`, finding the row whose `message_id` is equal to that number, and then telling me the value in that row's `sender` column. This can be done like this, where the `reply_to_id` variable is the number I gave you:

```py
data.loc[data["message_id"] == reply_to_id]["sender"]
```

Now this code returns a [pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html#pandas-series), but we didn't ask for a `Series`, we asked for a scalar value which is the name of the sender. So we need to extract that value from the Series. If there's only one value in the Series (you need to check that), we can extract it using [`pandas.Series.values[0]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html). So the code becomes like this:

```py
reply_to_sender_values = data.loc[data["message_id"] == reply_to_id]["sender"].values
if len(reply_to_sender_values) == 1:
    return reply_to_sender_values[0]
```

Now what would happen if I gave you a number that you didn't find in `message_id`? What would you do? You'd tell me that you found *nothing*. That translates to this:

```py
reply_to_sender_values = data.loc[data["message_id"] == reply_to_id]["sender"].values
if len(reply_to_sender_values) == 1:
    return reply_to_sender_values[0]
else:
    return ""
```

There's one more thing we need to pay attention to. As you said, the values in `reply_to_id` can be zero. So we need to take care of that:

```py
if(reply_to_id != 0):
    reply_to_sender_values = data.loc[data["message_id"] == reply_to_id]["sender"].values
    if len(reply_to_sender_values) == 1:
        return reply_to_sender_values[0]
    else:
        return ""
else:
    return ""
```

As you can see, we've just built a function to do what you would do by hand. Let's give it a name:

```py
def reply_to_sender(reply_to_id):
    if(reply_to_id != 0):
        reply_to_sender_values = data.loc[data["message_id"] == reply_to_id]["sender"].values
        if len(reply_to_sender_values) == 1:
            return reply_to_sender_values[0]
        else:
            return ""
    else:
        return ""
```

All there's left to do is to find a way to *apply* this function on all the rows in `reply_to_id` column of our `DataFrame`. Luckily, there's this method in `Pandas` that does just that. And it's called, you guessed it, [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Now it all comes together with this line of code:

```py
data["reply_to_sender"] = data["reply_to_id"].apply(lambda x: reply_to_sender(x))
```

---

One thing to notice, I tested this code in a *Jupyter Notebook.* If you want to run this code from a script, you need to pass the `DataFrame` to your `reply_to_sender` function. So the code changes to this:

```py
def reply_to_sender(data, reply_to_id):
    if(reply_to_id != 0):
        reply_to_sender_values = data.loc[data["message_id"] == reply_to_id]["sender"].values
        if len(reply_to_sender_values) == 1:
            return reply_to_sender_values[0]
        else:
            return ""
    else:
        return ""

data["reply_to_sender"] = data["reply_to_id"].apply(lambda x: reply_to_sender(data, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
mymap = {val: df.sender.loc[key] for key, val in df.message_id.to_dict().items()}
```

and then

```
df['reply_to_sender'] = df.reply_to_id.map(mymap)
```

This give you

```
   message_id  reply_to_id   sender reply_to_sender
0           1            0  Roozbeh             NaN
1           2            1     Amir         Roozbeh
2           3            0     Neda             NaN
3           4            2  Roozbeh            Amir
3           5            2     Neda            Amir
```